# VBA code to copy certain sheets from closed workbooks saved in a folder to a brand new workbook

Tags: vba, microsoft-excel-2013

I hope that there is a way to solve one of a very time consuming process which I currently perform manually.

I collect input from over 30 people who send to me their excel (xlsx format). So far, I have been opening each file, locating sheets named in certain way (ex. looked for sheets which contained word "Plan" in its name), copied found sheets into a brand new workbook and saved newly created workbook in specified location.

Can this process be automated through use of macro? Ideally I would like a macro which copies sheets which include "plan" in sheet name and without opening multiple workbooks, copies selected worksheets found in all files saved in a single folder and pastes those sheets into a brand new workbook. Is this possible to achieve?

I have the code below, but when I run this macro, nothing happens. Can you see what's causing the issue?

```
Sub CopyWorkSheets(strDirectory As String, strSheetName As String)
    Dim xlThisWB As Workbook
    Dim xlWB As Workbook
    Dim xlWS As Worksheet
    Dim strFileName As String
    Dim iCount As Integer

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    On Error Resume Next

    Set xlThisWB = ThisWorkbook
    strFileName = Dir(strDirectory & "*.xlsx")
    Do While strFileName <> ""
        If strFileName <> xlThisWB.Name Then
            With xlThisWB
                Set xlWB = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=strDirectory & strFileName)
                Set xlWS = xlWB.Worksheets(strSheetName)
                xlWS.Copy after:=xlThisWB.Worksheets(xlThisWB.Worksheets.Count)
                xlWB.Close
            End With
        End If
        strFileName = Dir()
    Loop
    On Error GoTo 0
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Apologies for asking a broad question. I was not aware of the required format. I have a below code, but when I run this macro, nothing happens. Can you see what's causing the issue?

Comment: Sub CopyWorkSheets(strDirectory As String, strSheetName As String)
 
    Dim xlThisWB As Workbook
    Dim xlWB As Workbook
    Dim xlWS As Worksheet
    Dim strFileName As String
    Dim iCount As Integer
 
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
 
    On Error Resume Next
 
    Set xlThisWB = ThisWorkbook
    strFileName = Dir(strDirectory & "*.xlsx")

Comment: Do While strFileName <> ""
      If strFileName <> xlThisWB.Name Then
        With xlThisWB
            Set xlWB = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=strDirectory & strFileName)
            Set xlWS = xlWB.Worksheets(strSheetName)
            xlWS.Copy after:=xlThisWB.Worksheets(xlThisWB.Worksheets.Count)
            xlWB.Close
        End With
      End If
      strFileName = Dir()
    Loop
 
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
 
End Sub

Comment: I copied my code in 2 comments as limit of characters did not allow me to copy all at once.

Comment: Please [edit] the question, and include the code properly formatted.

Comment: People can scan your code for an obvious error, but if it needs diagnostics, that would be much easier with more information.  Edit the question to include a brief explanation of what the code is supposed to do and the manner in which it fails.  What happens when it runs?  Do you get any error messages?  etc.  I'll vote to reopen, but you may not get much help without additional detail.

Comment: @fixer1234 - thanks for editing it; I also have an answer ready for it (I can infer the requirements from the initial post); can it be reopen? Thanks

Comment: @paulbica, you did the heavy lifting with the code, so you're the one who deserves the credit.  :-)  So far, it has 3 of the 5 votes needed to reopen.

Answer (score 1):

Add the procedures bellow in a new standard module and execute CopyWorkSheets():

After you run it, you'll see a new file in dest folder `Plans 2017-07-27 07-30.xlsx` (based on date)

---

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub CopyWorkSheets()
    Const PATH_FROM = "D:\Test1\"    '<- Update source folder path
    Const PATH_DEST = "D:\Test2\"    '<- Update destination path

    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet, wbResult As Workbook, fName As String, x As String

    If Len(Dir(PATH_FROM, vbDirectory)) > 0 And Len(Dir(PATH_DEST, vbDirectory)) > 0 Then
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Set wbResult = GetNewWB

        fName = Dir(PATH_FROM & "*.xlsx")
        Do While Len(fName) > 0
            x = PATH_FROM & fName
            Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=x, UpdateLinks:=False, ReadOnly:=True)
            For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
                If InStr(1, ws.Name, "Plan", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
                    ws.Copy After:=wbResult.Worksheets(wbResult.Worksheets.Count)
                End If
            Next
            wb.Close SaveChanges:=False
            fName = Dir()
        Loop

        fName = PATH_DEST & "Plans " & Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd hh-mm") & ".xlsx"
        SaveNewPlans wbResult, fName
        Application.EnableEvents = True
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End If
End Sub
```

---

```
Private Function GetNewWB() As Workbook
    Dim wb As Workbook, newSheets As Long

    newSheets = Application.SheetsInNewWorkbook
    Application.SheetsInNewWorkbook = 1
    Set wb = Workbooks.Add
    Application.SheetsInNewWorkbook = newSheets
    Set GetNewWB = wb
End Function
```

---

```
Private Sub SaveNewPlans(ByRef wb As Workbook, ByVal fName As String)
    With Application
        .DisplayAlerts = False
        With wb
            .Worksheets(1).Delete
            .Worksheets(1).Activate
            .SaveAs fName
            .Close SaveChanges:=False
        End With
        .DisplayAlerts = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With
End Sub
```

---

Your initial code should be called with a line like `CopyWorkSheets "D:\Test1\", "FileName.xlsx"` but it doesn't iterate over all files and it doesn't look for sheet names containing "Plans" in the name